# OpenGL screen-space translation of perspective camera view

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

I am using a perspective projection camera in OpenGL with an eye-target-up approach along the lines of `gluLookAt()`

I would like to move the entire 3d view to a different location within the 2d window, as shown in the image below:

[image]

I know this can be done with `glViewport()`, but I would ultimately like to be able to rotate the 3d view in addition to translating it, which I understand won't work with a glViewport approach.

I also understand that taking a non-glViewport approach will require the additional step of stenciling. I'll leave that step for later.

For now, I'm hoping to simply translate the 3d view as shown in the image above (ignoring the stenciling issue).

It seems like translating the projection matrix is the correct approach, however the translation extent is not what I expect. Perhaps I need to scale the parameter I'm using? In any case, I'm hoping someone can explain how to (more-or-less) simulate a translatable/rotatable glViewport for a 3d perspective view.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like `glViewport()` is what you want.  I don't know how rotation is connected to `glViewport()`, and I don't understand why you think it won't work.

Comment: Render to an image, and render _that_ to the screen, applying the appropriate transformation matrix. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577639/rotating-a-glviewport

Comment: I'm trying to draw a 3D perspective view inside a 2D GUI widget. In the diagram, I show the 2D widget being translated (in screenspace). The 3D view should translate along with the 2D widget. If the 2D widget were rotated by say 90def in z-axis, the 3D view should also be rotated. How would you do this with glViewport()

Comment: I was hoping to avoid rendering to an image. If the 2D widget changes size, I would have to regenerated the FBO numerous times.

Comment: What do you think happens when you resize a window though? The default framebuffer is resized and its previous contents are invalid. You're more likely to actually benefit from drawing to an FBO and blitting or stretching a textured quad rather than drawing straight to a window.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the FBO approach and it seems performant enough.

Answer (score 0):

You use `glViewport()`. For each view port, you set the viewport, setup model view matrix and draw scene.

For first viewport

```
glViewport (0, 0, window_width/2, window_height/2);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();

//do something with projection matrix

drawScene();
```

For second viewport

```
glViewport (window_width/2, 0, window_width/2, window_height/2);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();

//do something different with projection matrix

drawScene();
```

Comment: Will this approach allow rotation of the viewport as described in the question comments?

Comment: viewport will not be rotated. the content (the scene) that are rendered to this viewport will get rotated.